# Sum of coefficients of high degree terms in multivariate polynomial expansion

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, permutations, combinations

I want to expand the following multivariate polinomial
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i\right)^{n}$$
where $m\geq n$ are both integers.
For a fixed integer $k\in\{1,...,m\}$, how to find the sum of coefficients of (Note: original post asks for the number of) terms in the expansion such that (1) has $k$ unique $x_i$'s and (2) each $x_i$ has at least power 2?

For example, if $m=2$ and $n=4$, then 
$$
(x_1+x_2)^4 =x_1^4 + 4x_1^3x_2 + 6x_1^2x_2^2 + 4x_1x_2^3 + x_2^4.
$$
So let's say I want the coefficients for the term with two distinct $x$'s, i.e., $k=2$, I want to be able to calculate the value $6$ for the term $6x_1x_2$.

As a second example, if $m=2$ and $n=6$, then
$$
(x_1+x_2)^6 =x_1^6 + 6x_1^5x_2 + 15x_1^4x_2^2 + 20x_1^3x_2^3 + 15x_1^2x_2^4 + 6x_1x_2^5 + x_2^6
$$

For $(x_1+x_2)^6$ and $k=2$, I want to calculate the sum of coefficients for all the terms with $x_1^4x_2^2$, $x_1^3x_2^3$, and $x_1^2x_2^4$, so that's $15+20+15=50$.

Here are my thoughts: For a fixed integer $k$, the terms I am interested in has the form
$$
x_{q_1}^{p_1}...x_{q_k}^{p_k}
$$
where the $q$'s are unique and (1) $p_1+...+p_k=n$ and (2) $p_1,...,p_k\geq 2$.
This is a combinatorial problem but I don't quite know if there is a solution to it. I know that the number of non-negative integral solutions to (1) only is $n+k-1 \choose k-1$, but not quite sure how to incorporate the constraint (2).

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Minus 2, then the equation would have the only constraint "nonnegative".

Comment: Thanks xbh for the suggestion!

Comment: What do you mean by "the coefficient of terms ..." there are many such terms, and they have different coefficients.  If you just want the coefficient of a specific term, it is given by the multinomial theorem.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks! Maybe I ask for too much. I was hoping there may be a formula to calculate the sum of the coefficients that I look for (i.e., $k$ unique $x$'s and minimum power $2$ for each).

Comment: @saulspatz man..I am out of my mind...

Comment: @saulspatz anyway...I should calm down and work it out...Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem.  I'm dubious about finding a neat formula for the revised problem, though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your solution is correct, even without constraint $(2)$.  Notice that $m$ never appears in it.  I would say first that there are ${m\choose k}$ ways of determining which $k$ variables will appear, so that you have to multiply by ${m\choose k},$ but even this is not enough.  When you use stars and bars, you aren't enforcing the requirement that $p_i>0$.

For the actual problem, there are ${m\choose k}$ ways to choose the variables that will appear.  Then we must make the exponent of each of these equal to $2$ which leaves $n-2k$ exponents remaining to distribute among the $k$ variables.  By stars and bars, we can do this in ${n-2k+k-1\choose k-1}={n-k-1\choose k-1}$ ways so the answer is $$
{m\choose k}{n-k-1\choose k-1}$$

Comment: The solution makes sense, but somehow not giving the right answer...Let's say $m=2$ and $n=4$, so I am look at $(x_1+x_2)^4)=x_1^4+4x_1^3x_2+6x_1^2x_2^2+4x_1x_2^3+x_2^4$. If I set $k=2$, then the coefficient for $x_1^2x_2^2$ is $6$. But after setting $m=2$, $n=4$, and $k=2$, the formula gives 1...Is there anything missing in the formula?

Comment: @BenFung Your question asks for the number of terms, not the coefficient, and there is only one such term, namely $6x_1^2x_2.^2$

Comment: I'm very sorry, I will edit the question. Is there anyway to find the coefficient of such term?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking now.  What if there are many terms that meet the requirements? What do you want then?  If the expression is $(x_1+x_2)^6,$ what is the answer you are looking for?  It doesn't seem like you were looking for coefficients originally.  If you were, where did ${n+k-1\choose k-1}$ come from?

Comment: I added your example to the question as well, it is a much better example than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Note that by using the transformation  $q_i=p_i-2$, the question is equivalent to find $q_1,q_2,\ldots, q_n$ such that (1) $\sum_{i=1}^k q_i=n-2k$ and (2) $q_i\geq 0$. Thus, the number of solutions for this problem equal to $ {n-2k+k-1 \choose k-1}=  {n-k-1 \choose k-1}$.  Of course, you need to select $k \choose m$ to choose which $x_i$-'s will have a power of two, and thus the answer is

$$ {m \choose k} \cdot {n-k-1 \choose k-1}$$

Comment: This doesn't count the number of different ways to choose which $k$ variables  appear in the term.

Comment: You are right. Thanks!